# Returning the whole string when no match in a Powershell Substring(0, IndexOf)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have some Powershell that works with mail from Outlook folders. There is a footer on most emails starting with text `"------"`. I want to dump all text after this string.

I have added an expression to `Select-Object` as follows:

```
$cleanser = {($_.Body).Substring(0, ($_.Body).IndexOf("------"))}
$someObj | Select-Object -Property @{ Name = 'Body'; Expression = $cleanser}
```

This works when the `IndexOf()` returns a match... but when there is no match my `Select-Object` outputs `null`.

How can I update my expression to return the original string when `IndexOf` returns `null`?

Comment: `($_.Body)  -replace '(?s)------.*'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as countless times before, has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

Use PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), which implements regex-based string replacement that returns the input string *as-is* if the regex doesn't match:

```
# The script block to use in a calculated property with Select-Object later.
$cleanser = { $_.Body -replace '(?s)------.*' }
```

<sup>If you want to ensure that `------` only matches at the *start* of a line, use `(?sm)^------.*`; if you also want to remove the preceding newline, use `(?s)\r?\n------.*`</sup>

- `(?s)` is an inline regex option that makes `.` match newlines too, so that `.*` effectively matches all remaining text, across lines.
- By not specifying a replacement operand, `''` (the empty string) is implied, which effectively *removes* the matching part from the input string (technically, a *copy* of the original string with the matching part removed is returned).
- If regex `'(?s)------.*'` does *not* match, `$_.Body` is returned as-is (technically, it is the input string itself that is returned, not a copy).

The net effect is that anything starting with `------` is removed, *if present*.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Adam; my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @mklement0 and @PetSerAl Regular Expressions give the best answer. Yay! Regular Expressions to the rescue!

Edit:
Fixing my original post.

Going with @Adam's ideas of using a script block in the expression, you simply need to add more logic to the script block to check the index first before using it:

```
$cleanser = {
    $index = ($_.Body).IndexOf("------");
    if($index -eq -1){
        $index = $_.Body.Length
    };
    ($_.Body).Substring(0, $index)
}

$someObj | Select-Object -Property @{ Name = 'Body'; Expression = $cleanser}
```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, the problem wasn't that `$_.Body` isn't a string - the problem, which HAL9256 has since fixed, was that `$_.Body.IndexOf("------")` was called only _once_, outside the `$cleanser` script block that is used as part of a calculated property.

Comment: Thanks for this. I prefer the less verbose answer and I suspect (though have not tested) that it's probably more performant too. Thanks anyway :-)